# Future strings as URLs for CachedNetworkImage

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a way CachedNetworkImage can accept `Future<String>` as `imageUrl` ?

I'm trying to display user profile picture which is stored in Firebase Storage but because picture can change so does the download URL.

I know how to get the download URL but only managed to use it with `FutureBuilder` so far. Any suggestions on what I could make `async` so it waits for the URL ?

Or is there a way I can store URLs in the app itself ?

Answer (score 1):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step 1: You can put download URL logic in `getUrl()`, I use 3 seconds delay to simulate

```
Future<String> getUrl() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () {});
    return Future.value("https://via.placeholder.com/350x150");
  }
```

Step 2: Wrap `CachedNetworkImage` with `FutureBuilder`

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: _future,
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
      ...
        case ConnectionState.done:
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
           ...
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: CachedNetworkImage(
                imageUrl: snapshot.data,
                placeholder: (context, url) => Column(
                  children: [
                    Text("CachedNetworkImage"),
                    CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  ],
                ),
                errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
              ),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Future<String> _future;

  Future<String> getUrl() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () {});
    return Future.value("https://via.placeholder.com/350x150");
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _future = getUrl();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder(
            future: _future,
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.none:
                  return Text('none');
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return Center(
                      child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Text("Future builder"),
                      CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    ],
                  ));
                case ConnectionState.active:
                  return Text('');
                case ConnectionState.done:
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text(
                      '${snapshot.error}',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Center(
                      child: CachedNetworkImage(
                        imageUrl: snapshot.data,
                        placeholder: (context, url) => Column(
                          children: [
                            Text("CachedNetworkImage"),
                            CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          ],
                        ),
                        errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
              }
            }));
  }
}
```